# Does Next js production build need node_modules folder in the server?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am fairly new to Next js and its deployment process. I have recently converted one of my react js projects to Next js in order to advantage of the server-side rendering feature Next js offers. Now comes the deployment time, I figured out the Next build won't deploy without the `node_modules` folder present in the server. I use `getServerSideProps` in my pages and build with `"build": "next build"` command in package.json. The problem is my node_modules folder is close to 300MB (`.next` build adds about another 10MB) and I don't think it is the best practice to accompany this much weight with each deployment (I intend to have different instances of this build deployed, therefore 310MB X number of instances) in the server.
Am I doing something wrong here or is this the only way to accomplish this? I appreciate any answers. Thanks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After a bit of research, I am answering my own question. If you use `getServerSideProps` you cannot static export your project. Therefore the node_modules folder is required to deploy the project on the server. That doesn't mean you have to FTP the `node_modules`, you can do the npm build on the server-side which will download `node_modules` to the deployment folder. In my case, the deployment folder weighs around 310MB where the `node_modules` folder itself is around 300MB.

Comment: A guy from my company managed to do it without the folder, and we are using server side props. I dont know what sorcery he used. Will let you know if I figure out

Comment: @Brandon Any news?

Comment: Also interested in the sorcery - Any update @Brandon?

Comment: npm run build on target PC ?
i got the error "can't find next " , next need to install manual on customer PC ?

@Lance

Comment: additionally , i have removed the folder node_modules before cmd of npm run build

Answer (score 11):

**Update (11/14/22):**
The previously mentioned "output standalone" feature is no longer experimental:

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  output: 'standalone',
}
```

**Previous answer:**
The latest [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/deployment#docker-image) has a good example about how to create a standalone build with an excellent example of how to accomplish it [with docker](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-docker/Dockerfile). As of now, the feature is [experimental](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing).

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  experimental: {
    outputStandalone: true,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**As of September / 2023**

I found the same problem. My `node_modules` weights 380 MB. Definitely the building process should tree shake most of that.. and it does.

1. As it is described in the docs [Automatically Copying Traced Files](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/output#automatically-copying-traced-files) I have set my `next.config.js` to:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'standalone',
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

2. Run the build process by `npm run build`. The standalone folder generates in `app/.next/standalone`. This folder is an essence of your application with **all unnecessary staff removed**. It has a structure of:

```
app/.next/standalone/.next
app/.next/standalone/.env
app/.next/standalone/node_modules (only 30 MB)
app/.next/standalone/package.json
app/.next/standalone/server.js
```

3. Copy `app/.next/static` and `app/public` to `app/.next/standalone`. So now it looks like that:

```
...(elements mentioned earlier)
app/.next/standalone/server.js
app/.next/standalone/public -- copied from app/public
app/.next/standalone/.next/static -- copied from app/.next/static
```

4. Run production server in `app/.next/standalone` folder using command `node server.js`. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [@varcel/nnc][1] package to compile the project.

### In short:

**Install package:**
`npm i --save-dev @vercel/ncc` 
Change build command script inside **package.json**
From: `"build": "nest build",`
To: `"build": "ncc build src/main.ts -o dist",`

P.S. In my case entry point for application is **src/main.ts**
[1]: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vercel/ncc

Comment: Next and Nest are different things ;)

Answer (score 0):

For NX.dev users, a working solution:

Add in next.config.js

```
{
  ...
  output: 'standalone',
}
```

and then run:

```
nx build YOUR_NEXTJS_APP_NAME

mv dist/apps/YOUR_NEXTJS_APP_NAME/public dist/apps/YOUR_NEXTJS_APP_NAME/.next/standalone/dist/apps/YOUR_NEXTJS_APP_NAME

mv dist/apps/YOUR_NEXTJS_APP_NAME/.next/static dist/apps/YOUR_NEXTJS_APP_NAME/.next/standalone/dist/apps/YOUR_NEXTJS_APP_NAME/.next

node dist/apps/YOUR_NEXTJS_APP_NAME/.next/standalone/apps/YOUR_NEXTJS_APP_NAME/server.js
```